# How to not connect to a running instance of LibreOffice Server

Tags: java, openoffice.org, libreoffice, jodconverter

I am able to use LibreOffice headless server for file conversion in my application but my problem is concurrency.

I am using JODConverter as a Java API for connecting to the LibreOffice server using my java code.

If one user is using the LibreOffice server for converting the file, if at the same instance another user tries to convert his file then the server crashes.

Is there any method for using the LibreOffice server concurrently by many users??

Thanks in advance for your precious advises.